# Is there an up-to-date Getting Started guide for Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I thought I'd take a proper look at Castle Windsor and found a [Getting Started](http://www.castleproject.org/container/gettingstarted/index.html) page. A couple of pages [down](http://www.castleproject.org/container/gettingstarted/part1/requirements.html) I'm instructed to download an MSI installer distribution package. The link takes me to a [page full of download packages](http://www.castleproject.org/castle/download.html), none of which is MSI. I have no idea what I'm supposed to download.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial which I've written http://davidsiew.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/getting-started-with-castle-windsor-tutorial-part-1/.

Hopefully someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Castle project is currently in the process of migrating the documentation to [a new wiki](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) (and updating it along the way). The getting started guide has not yet been migrated unfortunately.

At this moment the best place to learn about Windsor is [grabbing a sample app](http://github.com/HEskandari/Castle-Windsor-Examples) (which is up to date for version 2.5) and going through the code. There's also a walkthough in the wiki for the sample, but it's being worked on and as of today only certain parts of it are covered (this is going to improve soon, make sure to leave your feedback!)